# Cant access open ports on local network including server, but can externally

Tags: networking, localhost, windows-server-2016, ports

I have recently purchased a new server, I have a pretty infuriating problem where ports that I open are accessible to external devices but can't be accessed by any device on the local network and even the server itself.

Couple things to note:

- Firewall is disabled
- Router: CentryLink Technicolor C1100T
- Currently Connected to router via powerline adapters
- Ports:

  TCP or UDP  32400
  TCP or UDP  80 thru 81
  TCP or UDP  3389
  TCP or UDP  7878
  TCP or UDP  8989
  TCP or UDP  9088
  TCP or UDP  5000
  TCP or UDP  9117
  TCP or UDP  25565
  TCP or UDP  25580 thru 25590
  TCP or UDP  21

**Please ask any questions you have.

Comment: I wish I could add a bounty on this stuff.

Comment: 1) Please add an OS tag for the server. 2) Systematically debug the problem. E.g. on Linux: Start a very simple service using e.g. netcat, `netcat -l 12345`. Try to connect from this service on the server with `echo foo | netcat localhost 12345`. If this doesn't work, note the error message. Then you can start checking the details, i.e. `iptables`, routes etc, `tcpdump -ni lo`. With the information you provided it's impossible to find the reason.

Comment: @dirkt Windows Server 2016, i agree. I just didnt know what else to put.

Comment: Based on my experience with the Windows Firewall, in most of the cases it's still the Firewall, even if you think you have disabled it. So that's the first place I'd look.

Comment: I've opened all ports with a rule. What else could I add?

Comment: First thing to try is to completely disable the firewall, and see if it works then. If it does, you know it's the firewall, so you have narrowed down the problem, and can look at the rules. If it doesn't, you need to look somewhere else. That's what "systematically debugging" means: Move whole components out of the way, so you can narrow down to the source of the problem.

Comment: Which IP address are you using for connecting the devices: The internal one of the server (`192.168.*`) or the external/public one of the router? You should be using the internal one.

Comment: @harrymc I'm using the internal IP.

Comment: @dirkt Firewall is already disabled, where would you look next?

Comment: Are the other devices using WiFi or Ethernet? If only WiFi, then try Ethernet.

Comment: Both, and that's including the server itself